# C# How do I get string from Task<string> after a web request?

Tags: c#

I have this code, which is supposed to return an authentication token from an API I have built. I have gone for an asynchronous approach but now I am not sure what to do in my specific case to get the string token, not the Task, Here is my code:

```
    private async Task<string> AuthLogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        string username = user;
        string password = pass;
        string url = "http://localhost:8000/login";

        try {
            //retrieve auth token from /login
            var client = new HttpClient ();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            string jsonData = "{\"username\":" + "\"" + username + "\",\"password\":" + "\"" + password + "\"}";

            var content = new StringContent (jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/type");
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync (new Uri (url), content);

            string s = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
            string result = Convert.ToString (s);
            //some formatting to extract the actual token string
            string[] tokenParts = result.Split (':');
            string token = tokenParts[1].Replace ("\"", "");

            return token;

        }
        catch (WebException) {
            //error handling here
            return null;
        }

    }

    public string StoreTokenFromLogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        var token = AuthLogin (user, pass).Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token.GetType ());

        return token; //should be a string
    }
```

Then, in my page view, I have an event handler that does this:

```
loginButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
             Authentication a = new Authentication();
             string tok = a.StoreTokenFromLogin(usernameInput.Text, passwordInput.Text);

            authLabel.Text = tok;

        };
```

However, when I click the button, the app freezes. ( I am in Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: What type is `token`? Your method returns a `Task<string>` and the `Task<string>.Result` should return the `string`.

Comment: I just tried to get the result of the AuthLogin(), which should give me a string but doesn't. I may be wrong though, because I ended up confusing myself too much.

Comment: Yes, Task<T>.Result is the correct way to get the `string`. What **exactly** does it return?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to `await` the `AuthLogin()`?

Comment: If you're going to asynchronous then you'd `await` the `Task` to get the result.  Of course that means that the method with the `await` has to be `async` and it's callers would need to `await` and it should bubble up to a point were you want to fire an forget, usually in a event handler, and that would be an `async void` method (one of the few times you should use that instead of `async Task`).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Token will be a string. Null if the WebException is raised. No doubt about that.

Comment: I am going to test this out from scratch and get back in a second.

Comment: so @juharr is right, you'll need to await. Forget the .Result

Comment: @alexcons: I have a blog post that describes [why `Result` deadlocks your application](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your event handler to this

```
loginButton.Clicked += async(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    Authentication a = new Authentication();
    string tok = await a.StoreTokenFromLogin(usernameInput.Text, passwordInput.Text);
    authLabel.Text = tok;
};
```

That will await the call to get the token without tying up the current thread (presumably the UI thread).

And your `StoreTokenFromLogin` to this.

```
public async Task<string> StoreTokenFromLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    var token = await AuthLogin (user, pass);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token.GetType ());

    return token; //should be a string
}
```

Basically the idea is that when you start using `async` and `await` it's going to bubble up through your method calls until you get to something that should do a fire and forget (`async void`), which in this case is your event handler.

If you do use `Task.Result` then you are blocking the current thread while waiting and defeating the point of using `async`- `await`.